# Create new column based on date column Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a new column of students' grade levels based on their DOB. The cut off dates for 1st grade would be 2014/09/02 - 2015/09/01. Is there a simple solution for this besides making a long if/elif statement. Thanks.

| Name | DOB |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | 2011/06/20 |
| Mike | 2009/02/19 |
| Kevin | 2012/12/22 |

Comment: Probably. But do you really think your description is sufficient to be able to help you? You should provide a MRE.

Comment: Trying to put one in now, sorry not super familiar with formatting on here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.cut()`, which also supports custom bins.

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

dob = {
    'Sally': '2011/06/20',
    'Mike': '2009/02/19',
    'Kevin': '2012/12/22',
    'Ron': '2009/09/01',
}
dob = pd.Series(dob).astype('datetime64').rename("DOB").to_frame()

grades = [
    '2008/9/1',
    '2009/9/1',
    '2010/9/1',
    '2011/9/1',
    '2012/9/1',
    '2013/9/1',
]
grades = pd.Series(grades).astype('datetime64')

dob['grade'] = pd.cut(dob['DOB'], grades, labels = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
print(dob.sort_values('DOB'))

             DOB grade
Mike  2009-02-19     5
Ron   2009-09-01     5
Sally 2011-06-20     3
Kevin 2012-12-22     1
```

I sorted the data frame by date of birth, to show that oldest students are in the highest grades.
​